# Simple extension $K( \alpha)$ over $K$ of degree 2, show $ \alpha^2 \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to show that if $K( \alpha)$ over $K$ is an extension of degree 2, then $ \alpha^2 \in K$ if the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$.

Let's suppose the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha$ is $f(t) = t^2 +bt + c$.

I am able to use the quadratic formula, and I can show that both roots of $f$ are in this extension (i.e. $K (\alpha) = K( \alpha, \beta)$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of $f$), but I don't see how this helps. The degree of the extension only tells me immediately $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ are not linearly independent, but that only immediately says they satisfy a quadratic, not that $\alpha \in K$.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Let $\alpha=(\sqrt5-1)/2$. Then $\alpha^2\notin \mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{R}(\alpha)$ is a simple extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of degree $2$.

Comment: @EclipseSun : you probably mean $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @tristan Yes. It should be $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If you have trouble proving it true, have you considered that it might not be? And tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: @EclipseSun But cant we look at $ \mathbb{Q} ( \alpha)  $ as $ \mathbb{Q} ( 2*a -1) $ in this case? I should have clarified that I am asking for it to be true for some $ \alpha$, not necessarily the original stated to give the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite likely you think this is true because it's true for all the "standard" field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ such as $\mathbb{Q(i),Q(\sqrt2),Q(\sqrt5)}$. In fact, all degree 2 field extensions of a field $\mathbb{F}$ are generated by an element of the form $\alpha = \sqrt{a}$ where $a \in \mathbb{F}$ so long as $char(\mathbb{F}) \neq 2$. But just think about the fact $\mathbb{Q(\alpha}) = \mathbb{Q(\alpha+1)}$ and certainly for all those same fields $(\alpha+1)^2 \notin \mathbb{Q} $

And I suppose it might be worth mentioning that in characteristic 2 this reasoning does not work as $(\alpha +1)^2 = \alpha^2 +1$.